# C programming find length of 2 Dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

My program grabs command line arguements with argc and argv[]. My question is how can I find the length of argv[1][i].

My code that grabs length of argv[]

```
int my_strlen(char input[]){ 
    int len = 0;
    while(input[len] != '\0'){
       ++len;
    }
    return len;
}
```

but when I try to find argv[1][len] I get a subscripted value is neither array nor pointer:
my attempt

```
int my_strlen(char input[]){
   int len = 0;
   while((input[1][len] - '0') != '\0'){
      ++len;
   }
   return len;
}
```

FULL CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int my_strlen(char input[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int length = 0;
length = my_strlen(argv[1]);
long numberArr[length];
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
  numberArr[i] = argv[1][i] - '0';
}

 return 0;
}

int my_strlen(char input[]){
 int len = 0;
 while((input[1][len] - '0') != '\0'){
  ++len;
 }
 return len;
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: `argv` is a 2-dimensional array of characters (`char`), meaning that it is a 1-dimensional array of strings.

Comment: @Gabe: Thanks, I'm in the early stages of learning C, so since there is no string type in C I've been a little confused when people refer to them as "strings". But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused about the argv content.  The OS will pass a number of ASCIIZ strings, such that invoking my_program with arguments ala...

```
my_program first second third
```

...is similar to having the following declaration in your program...

```
int argc = 4;
const char* argv[4] = { "my_program", "first", "second", "third" };
```

Hence, when you index into `argv[1][i]` you're getting the i-th character in the string "first".  That's only valid for values of i between 0 (which yields 'f'), and 5 (which indexes to the terminating NUL character '\0').

So, there no two-dimensional N*M array, but there is an array of pointers-to-(array-of-char).  You can invoke the normal `strlen()` function as in `strlen(argv[1])` to find out the number of characters in each argument.  Only `argc` tells you the total number of elements in `argv`.

Does that help?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, So I should treat argv[1] as a string and use strlen(argv[1]) in order to get string length? I was using this before and was getting sometimes getting a segmentation fault error

Comment: @Grant: Yes, that's the right approach. Did you check argc before trying to use argv[1]? If you forget to provide a command line argument, then you can't use strlen(argv[1]). That's pretty easy to do in shells where some environment variable might not be set etc.. Remember too that the program name is `argv[0]` and accounts for `argc` of `1`, hence the last argument is still only `argv[argc - 1]`.  Put another way, check `argc > 1` to make sure you've got an `argv[1]`.  If you do find you've still got a problem, do post the broken code.

Comment: To clarify, there's a difference between a two dimensional array of characters, and an array of strings (char pointers).  Imagine a case where (making addresses up) argv[0] = 0x123456. argv[1] could potentially be 0x055555.  argv is not the same thing as a matrix of chars...

Comment: @Tony: Yes I have it checking argc (first thing I do). I'm not sure what exactly was being inputted into it that made it return a segmentation error because I'm using a separate program that the professor uses to grade it (I'll have to mess with it). Quick question, the const before char* argv[4] declares it as a string? (I know there isn't a string type in C).

Comment: @Grant: the `const` just asks the compiler to generate an error if you accidentally try to modify the characters that the pointer points to.  Normally, that's a good idea for argv as it's rare that you want to modify them but could accidentally change them, producing confusing bugs.  It's an excellent idea when creating a pointer to string literals (e.g. "quoted text in your program"), as the OS probably loads them into read-only memory and will fail at run-time if you try to write to them: better to know about the problem at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, you're passing `argv[1]` to `my_strlen`. That means `my_strlen` just receives a normal, single-dimension string. It doesn't need to do `input[1][len]`, just `input[len]`.

Comment: I had that before. However, sometimes I would get a segmentation fault which is why I was trying it a bit different

Comment: Even with that fixed, `my_strlen()` looped while `input[len] - '0' != '\0'`: but the "- '0'" is effectively saying subtract the numeric value used to encode the character zero/'0' (in ASCII, 48 decimal), and make sure the result's not the numeric value used to encode the character '\0' (always 0).  Given "x - y != 0" is equivalent to "x != y", you're just saying loop until you find a zero/'0' character.  But, you do want to check for ASCII NUL/'\0' - just use `while (input[len] != '\0')`, or equivalently `while (input[len])`, which leverages C interpreting 0 as false, non-0 as true.

Comment: @Grant: looking again, you have another problem. The end of a string is signaled by a character with the value '\0', so your while loop should be more like `while (input[len] != '\0')`.